# understanding the Modulo logic

Tags: mysql, sql

Please consider the following code snippet from a SQL Query:

```
WHERE  TableType_ti = 1 
AND TableID_int MOD 2 = 0 
AND TaskScheduled_dt < NOW()
```

I don't understand, what does the line `AND TableID_int MOD 2 = 0` is actually doing? If I have understood correctly, `TableID_int MOD 2` value is getting evalueted first and then it is compared with `0` .

Please let me know if I am wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You're not wrong. I think mod is always executed first, in every language. Whenever you're not sure, just parenthensize it: `(x mod 2) = 0`

Comment: Here is the complete list of operator precedence: [mysql/operator-precedence.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html). And, yes 'mod' is higher than '='. so the expression return 0 or 1 and is then compared

Answer (score 1):

The modulus operator returns the remainder when two integers are divided by each other.  So:

- 5 mod 2 = 1
- 9 mod 3 = 0
- 10 mod 6 = 4

When you take an integer mod 2, you are testing for whether it is even or odd.  Even is `0` and odd is `1`.